# Prove or disprove that the inequality is valid if $x,y,z$ are positive numbers and $xyz=1$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Prove or disprove that the inequality
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}} \geq 1$$
is valid if $x,y,z$ are positive numbers and $$xyz=1.$$

My solution is:
Let $$x=\dfrac{a}{b}, y=\dfrac{b}{c}, z=\dfrac{c}{a}.$$
So we have
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{a}{b}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{b}{c}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{c}{a}}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{a+b}{b}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{b+c}{c}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{c+a}{a}}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{c+b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a+c}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{bb}{b(a+b)}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{cc}{c(c+b)}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{aa}{a(a+c)}}.$$
Then we can use this:
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}\geq\dfrac{2}{x+y}.$$
So we have
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{bb}{b(a+b)}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{cc}{c(c+b)}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{aa}{a(a+c)}} \geq \dfrac{2b}{2b+a}+\dfrac{2c}{2c+b}+\dfrac{2a}{2a+c}.$$
Then we can use this:
$$\dfrac{a}{x}+\dfrac{b}{y}+\dfrac{c}{z} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{abc}{xyz}}.$$
So we have
$$\dfrac{2b}{2b+a}+\dfrac{2c}{2c+b}+\dfrac{2a}{2a+c} \geq 3 \sqrt[3] {\dfrac{8abc}{(2b+a)(2c+b)(2a+c)}}.$$
The question is what should I do next? Is it already obvious that
$$3 \sqrt[3] {\dfrac{8abc}{(2b+a)(2c+b)(2a+c)}} \geq 1?$$
Any hint would help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Note that your final claim isn't true, eg for $ a = 100, b = 1, c = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=\frac{a}{b},$ $y=\frac{b}{c}$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Thus, $z=\frac{c}{a}$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=1.$$

Comment: Why is this inequality valid?

Comment: @Alice Malinova because $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}\geq\sqrt{a+b}.$

Comment: okay, but so far I don't see why there is $$\sqrt{c}$$ in the first fraction? Isn't just $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt(a+b) \geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}?$$

Comment: @Alice Malinova $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{b}}}=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a+b}}\geq\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}.$

Comment: now I see, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2):

This is almost the same as the other answer and just slightly different: $\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{c+b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a+c}}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a+b+c}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{a+b+c}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a+b+c}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}> 1.$ Done.

Comment: so we can just add \sqrt{c} in the first denominator (etc) to make our right fraction less than left?

Comment: No, you add $c$ only. Not $\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: ok, now I see, thanks a lot!